# on.blur and on.click triggered prior to ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I have two events and the second one triggers an Ajax call. (A click creates an input in the `<td>` which is overwritten by the success event afterwards - so the input on the blur is correct)

```
$(document).on("click","#"+table_id+" td",function(e)

$(document).on("blur","#"+table_id+" td input",function(e)
  ajax(ajaxStatements,"update");
```

If I click on a `<td>` and then click on an empty space afterwards it goes as follows:

CLICK EVENT -----------
BLUR EVENT #######
AJAX EVENT +++++++

If I click on a `<td>` and then follow up with another click on another `<td>` it doesn't behave properly.

CLICK EVENT -----------
BLUR EVENT #######
AJAX EVENT +++++++
CLICK EVENT -----------

This is what I want. **But** then - *and this is the Question* - the response varies and does this:

CLICK EVENT -----------
BLUR EVENT #######
CLICK EVENT -----------
AJAX EVENT +++++++

Why does the new click-event trigger before the ajax call even if the blur event is called?

Comment: because you delegated your event

Comment: Can you include your ajax code as well? This sounds like a problem where your ajax event (++++++++) only happens after it been sent, and not before.

Comment: I believe you are trying to have an inline editing of the table. Just because one td editing failed, you should not block the user from editing other td as well. So, `click`, `blur`, `click`, `ajax` might be the correct flow. If you are calling ajax inside blur event handler, functional scope allows you to send correct request as well.

Comment: @madalinivascu I didn't know definitely looking into that - thx.

Comment: @nightgaunt the problem was that the new click somehow resulted in being the success field for the old blur which was a total mess :D but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because AJAX is asynchronous so your request and the click event is triggered simultaneously.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
 async:false,
})
```

Comment: Thanks mate that one troubled me so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ajax() request in asynchronous and it do not wait for the ajax() to complete. So if you want to hold the process till ajax do not complete, try this:

```
$.ajax({
   async:false,
});
```

[Ajax Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Darn, it's also the right answer sry Rahul was just a little faster, but thx a lot as well.